# If PRF is non invertible, why does Ctr-mode work?

Tags: cbc, pseudo-random-function, ctr

I am currently taking Dan Boneh's Cryptography I course online. 
I have just finished the segment discussing the Cipher Block Chaining and Counter-Mode.
I am having difficulty understanding why Ctr-Mode works as an encryption algorithm as PRFs are fundamentally non invertible, as per my understanding. Any clarification on this would be highly appreciated!

Comment: For any length, $\: \langle$ binary_strings_of_that_length , xor $\rangle \:$ is an [abelian group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_group#Definition). $\hspace{1.92 in}$ For any length, each element of that group is its own inverse. $\;\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer I've generated an answer without (too much) math in it, but I would happily vote up an answer that explains the mathematics behind it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CTR consists of two parts: construction the *key stream* using a counter, and XOR-ing the output of the key stream with the plaintext/ciphertext. The key stream *can* be generated using a PRF, in which case it is of course not invertible. The key stream can also be created using a PRP (e.g. a block cipher like AES) in which case it is invertible.

As indicated, CTR mode encryption requires the XOR-ing of the plaintext / ciphertext as well. A PRF is a *pseudo* random function, so given the same input it will generate the same key stream. The XOR-ing of the key stream is perfectly reversible; you just have to perform the XOR with the key stream again. So CTR mode encryption is always reversible, even when it relies on a PRF to generate the key stream.

Because of this, CTR-mode is indeed *not* a PRF.